# Can't access build variables from powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to use the [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) in a script. According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops) I should be able to use the following:

```
Write-Host "BUILD_DATE: $Env:BUILD_DATE"
Write-Host "BUILD_REV: $Env:BUILD_REV"
```

However, I only get the following output

```
BUILD_DATE:
BUILD_REV:
```

I've also tried this syntax:

```
Write-Host "BUILD_DATE: $(Env:BUILD_DATE)"
Write-Host "BUILD_REV: $(Env:BUILD_REV)"

Write-Host "BUILD_DATE: $(Build.Date)"
Write-Host "BUILD_REV: $(Build.Rev)"
```

But the first segment gives `The term 'Env:BUILD_DATE' is not recognized` and the second segment gives `The term 'Build.Date' is not recognized`

How can I use the build variables in my script?

Comment: first one should work. oh wait, variable called build_Date doesnt exist, same as build_rev

Comment: The "Build number format" contains `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` by default, and I want to access those from my script (and format them the same way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I know virtually nothing about Azure pipelines, so my answer is based on reading the docs. Do let us know if I got things wrong.</sup>

Your **first command uses the correct *syntax*** for referencing environment variables in PowerShell (also inside an expandable (double-quoted) string).
(The other commands, based on subexpression operator `$(...)`, mistakenly try to execute *commands* named `Env:BUILD_DAT`, ... rather than referencing variables.)

Your problem seems to be that **the targeted environment variables *do not exist***.

The [list of predefined variables that are exposed as environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) does *not* contain variables named `Build.Date` / `$env:BUILD_DATE` and `Build.Rev` / `$env:BUILD_REV`.

By contrast, variables named `Date` and `Rev` seemingly do exist - as you state, they are used in the default format definition for the `Build.BuildNumber` / `$Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` *build variable*, `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` - but are seemingly of a *different kind not exposed as env. vars.* (unlike `Build.BuildNumber` / `$Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` itself, which *is* exposed).

(I don't know where these variables are defined or how they are classified, and where this is documented - do tell us if you know.)

A quick **workaround** would be to split the value of `$Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER` into its constituent parts:

```
# Split the build number into date and revision, by "."
$date, $rev = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER -split '\.'

"BUILD_DATE: $date"
"BUILD_REV: $rev"
```